# Where can I find LEGO Doctor Who sunglasses and guitar?

Tags: minifigures

Where can I find LEGO minifigure sunglasses in black and a rock band guitar for the new Doctor Who set? I have searched on ebay and LEGO.com.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com). They have a whole range of [Minifig heads with sunglasses](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=minifig%20sunglasses) - pick the one you like.

[image]

For guitars, [this search](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=utensil%20guitar) shows what BrickLink has available. As an example:

[image]

Note that BrickLink is a marketplace - they give you access to thousands of individual sellers with their own stores. You might want to find a seller who has both items you like in stock, so you can purchase and only pay 1 shipping/handling fee.